# Length of each string in a NumPy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is there any builtin operation in NumPy that returns the length of each string in an array?

I don't think any of the [NumPy string operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/routines.char.html) does that, is this correct?

I can do it with a `for` loop, but maybe there's something more efficient?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(['Hello', 'foo', 'and', 'whatsoever'], dtype='S256')

sizes = []
for i in arr:
    sizes.append(len(i))

print(sizes)
[5, 3, 3, 10]
```

Comment: For modest size arrays, the list comprehension equivalent is good: `[len(i) for i in arr]`.   The `np.char` functions aren't speedy either, since they still have to apply `string` methods to each element.  Don't

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `vectorize` of `numpy`. It is much faster.

```
mylen = np.vectorize(len)
print mylen(arr)
```

Comment: In my timings `mylen` is noticeably slower than the list comprehension for this small example array, and barely faster for one that is 1000x large.  `vectorize` does not promise speed.  It does make iterating over all elements of a multidimensional array easier.

Comment: @hpaulj i was referring to for loop. It is faster than normal for and if data is huge, it is still faster than list comprehension. Data matters. :)

Comment: Comparing to pandas, this was faster than `df['s'].str.len()`

Comment: Is there no one-liner for this standard operation in Numpy? `np.vectorize(len)(arr)` is weird.

Comment: The reason `np.vectorize` is not faster is because `np.vectorize` just runs a Python for loop—it does _not_ compile. This deficiency is, in fact, why Numba was written. Here's Travis Oliphant (author of NumPy) saying exactly that: https://youtu.be/QpaapVaL8Fw?t=1621

Answer (score 16):

UPDATE 06/20: Cater for u+0000 character and non-contiguous inputs - thanks @ M1L0U

Here is a comparison of a couple of methods.

Observations:

- For input size >1000 lines, viewcasting + `argmax` is consistently and by a large margin fastest.
- Python solutions profit from converting the array to a list first.
- `map` beats list comprehension
- `np.frompyfunc` and to a lesser degree `np.vectorize` fare better than their reputation

.

```
 contiguous
method ↓↓                  size →→  |     10|    100|   1000|  10000| 100000|1000000
------------------------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
np.char.str_len                     |  0.006|  0.037|  0.350|  3.566| 34.781|345.803
list comprehension                  |  0.005|  0.036|  0.312|  2.970| 28.783|293.715
list comprehension after .tolist()  |  0.002|  0.011|  0.117|  1.119| 12.863|133.886
map                                 |  0.002|  0.008|  0.080|  0.745|  9.374|103.749
np.frompyfunc                       |  0.004|  0.011|  0.089|  0.861|  8.824| 88.739
np.vectorize                        |  0.025|  0.032|  0.132|  1.046| 12.112|133.863
safe argmax                         |  0.026|  0.026|  0.056|  0.290|  2.827| 32.583

 non-contiguous
method ↓↓                  size →→  |     10|    100|   1000|  10000| 100000|1000000
------------------------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
np.char.str_len                     |  0.006|  0.037|  0.349|  3.575| 34.525|344.859
list comprehension                  |  0.005|  0.032|  0.306|  2.963| 29.445|292.527
list comprehension after .tolist()  |  0.002|  0.011|  0.117|  1.043| 11.081|130.644
map                                 |  0.002|  0.008|  0.081|  0.731|  7.967| 99.848
np.frompyfunc                       |  0.005|  0.012|  0.099|  0.885|  9.221| 92.700
np.vectorize                        |  0.025|  0.033|  0.146|  1.063| 11.844|134.505
safe argmax                         |  0.026|  0.026|  0.057|  0.291|  2.997| 31.161
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

flist = []
def timeme(name):
    def wrap_gen(f):
        flist.append((name, f))
        return(f)
    return wrap_gen

@timeme("np.char.str_len")
def np_char():
    return np.char.str_len(A)

@timeme("list comprehension")
def lst_cmp():
    return [len(a) for a in A]

@timeme("list comprehension after .tolist()")
def lst_cmp_opt():
    return [len(a) for a in A.tolist()]

@timeme("map")
def map_():
    return list(map(len, A.tolist()))

@timeme("np.frompyfunc")
def np_fpf():
    return np.frompyfunc(len, 1, 1)(A)

@timeme("np.vectorize")
def np_vect():
    return np.vectorize(len)(A)
    
@timeme("safe argmax")
def np_safe():
    assert A.dtype.kind=="U"
    # work around numpy's refusal to viewcast non contiguous arrays
    v = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        A[0,None].view("u4"),(A.size,A.itemsize>>2),(A.strides[0],4))
    v = v[:,::-1].astype(bool)
    l = v.argmax(1)
    empty = (~(v[:,0]|l.astype(bool))).nonzero()
    l = v.shape[1]-l
    l[empty] = 0
    return l
    
A = np.random.choice(
    "Blind\x00text do not use the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog "
    .split(" "),1000000)[::2]

for _, f in flist[:-1]:
    assert (f()==flist[-1][1]()).all()

from timeit import timeit

for j,tag in [(1,"contiguous"),(2,"non-contiguous")]:
    print('\n',tag)
    L = ['|+' + len(flist)*'|',
         [f"{'method ↓↓                  size →→':36s}", 36*'-']
         + [f"{name:36s}" for name, f in flist]]
    for N in (10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000):
        A = np.random.choice("Blind\x00text do not use the quick brown fox"
                             " jumps over the lazy dog ".split(" "),j*N)[::j]
        L.append([f"{N:>7d}", 7*'-']
                 + [f"{timeit(f, number=10)*100:7.3f}" for name, f in flist])
    for sep, *line in zip(*L):
        print(*line, sep=sep)
```

Comment: Great answer! The trick with the `argmin` is nice, but it has one edge case: it finds the first `'\x00'`, which not necessarily the end of the string. In most cases, especially unicode strings, the only '\x00' are at the end, but some strings (like bytes) may contain some at any position. In order to find the size of the string, we need to count how many `'\x00'` there are starting from the right. This may be done for instance by `(numpy.cumsum((v != 0)[:, ::-1],axis=1) > 0).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Hi @M1L0U It has been a while since I wrote that answer, but I think it is correct. Note that I'm not casting to byte but to uint32 matching the fact that numpy `U...` dtype is a 4 byte fixed width encoding. I don't think four aligned zero bytes are possible anywhere but as endmarker. Or are they?

Comment: It is technically possible, but very strange. I don't see use cases except "wrongly" converting raw bytes into unicode strings. `A = numpy.array([ 'ABC\x00DEF', 'A\x00BC'])` is a perfectly valid `U7` array from `numpy`'s point of view

Comment: @M1L0U Holy cow, you are right. Apparently, u+0000 is valid unicode. I'll update the post.

Comment: And because I love edge cases, here is another one ^^ (might be useful to someone Googling for this). If the array in not C-continuous, then the `view(np.uint32)` will fail. Such things typically occur after slicing with `step!=1`. For instance doing `A[::-1]`. To fix this, you can add `A = numpy.asarray(A, order='C')` before the `.view`. Note that it copies the data only when needed

Comment: @M1L0U The copy can be avoided in either case with a bit of black magic, see updated post if you are interested. Any more edge cases you can think of ;-) ?

Answer (score 12):

Using `str_len` from `Numpy`:

```
sizes = np.char.str_len(arr)
```

str_len documentation: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.char.str_len.html

Comment: This is by far the best answer to the question. Please upvote it! It needs to be at the top!

Answer (score 7):

For me this would be the way to go :

```
sizes = [len(i) for i in arr]
```