# Get the number entries in a list entry of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, list, series

I have a pandas dataframe with various columns, one of which is a string that I split into a list, using the split command:

```
    import Pandas as pd

    csvRead = pd.read_csv('../data/Data.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame(csvRead)

    df['split_string'] = df['string'].str.split(r'[ ]')

    idx = 0
    for i in df['split_string']:
        df['split_string_counts'][idf] = len(i)
        i += 1
```

Now I want to vectorize the for statement, because there is no standard command in the Pandas.Series pacakge that can count the number of elements for the list given by the split command. The dataframe df has more than 2 million entries, so the for is very inefficient.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Show us a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately here vectorized is not possible, but if no missing values you can use list comprehensions:

```
#DataFrame constructor is not necessary, because read_csv return DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('../data/Data.csv')

df['split_string'] = [x.split() for x in df['string']]
df['split_string_counts'] = [len(x) for x in df['split_string']]
```

If possible missing values use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df['split_string'] = df['string'].str.split()
df['split_string_counts'] = df['split_string'].str.len()
```

Comment: Thanks! df['split_string_counts'] = df['split_string'].str.len() worked!

Comment: @rjc - Super, glad can help!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by accessing the series's underlying `.values`:

```
import numpy as np

mylen = np.vectorize(len)
df['split_string_counts'] = mylen(df['split_string'].values)
```

but the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44587916/425458) suggest it won't be any faster than the list comprehensions that jezrael suggests.